# How to extract first element of a tuple, which is a column in a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows,

```
id          text             senti_score
1           text A            (0.5,1)
2           text B             (0.4,0.7)
3           Nan                 None
4           text c             (0.2,0.4)

Expected output,
id          text             senti_score       new_Score
1           text A            (0.5,1)            0.5
2           text B             (0.4,0.7)         0.4
3           Nan                 None             None
4           text c             (0.2,0.4)          0.2
```

Please note there some records which does not have senti_Score and it just has "None" in it.

Can someone please help me how to get this using python? Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a system to format your code. What you posted is not Python code. Without a minimal example, we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated now

Comment: @BlueSheepToken this assigns first element of first tuple to all the rows i.e, 0.5 to all the rows.

Comment: @mavles Better but you should include the code to generate the dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use pandas `str` accessor + `.get`

```
df['senti_score'].str[0]
```

or

```
df['senti_score'].str.get(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to **filter** `None` data

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'text': ["a" , "b", "c", "d"], 'senti_score': [(0.5, 1), (0.4, 0.7), (0.2, 0.4), None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df[df['senti_score'].notnull()]
df['new_score'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['senti_score'][0], axis=1)
print(df)

>>>   text senti_score  new_score
>>> 0    a    (0.5, 1)        0.5
>>> 1    b  (0.4, 0.7)        0.4
>>> 2    c  (0.2, 0.4)        0.2
```

In case you want to **skip** `None` data

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'text': ["a" , "b", "c", "d"], 'senti_score': [(0.5, 1), (0.4, 0.7), (0.2, 0.4), None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['new_score'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['senti_score'][0] if row['senti_score'] is not None else None, axis=1)
print(df)

>>>>   text senti_score  new_score
>>>> 0    a    (0.5, 1)        0.5
>>>> 1    b  (0.4, 0.7)        0.4
>>>> 2    c  (0.2, 0.4)        0.2
>>>> 3    d        None        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks but what if i have none in some of the rows. "("'NoneType' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index 12')". Is there a way to skip none rows?

Answer (score 0):

Returns the first element of the tuple, or `default` if missing

```
from operator import itemgetter as at
default = 0
df['senti_score'].fillna((default,)).apply(at(0))
```

Comment: this says "we cant pass a tuple"